# How to design vetoable events in event sourcing/ eventuate

Tags: event-sourcing

Let us assume having a simple use case (java/ microservice/ event sourcing/ eventuate):

- Microservice A introduces a user entity
- Microservice B introduces a synchronization from our users to some external user storage (Maybe ldap etc.)

Let us assume B is not able to change user names for some technical reason but A for itself allows changing of user names.

How to implement this? In classic monoliths we may build something around 
java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport. In microservice I get into trouble. My first thought was to devide it into three events.

First we publish an event saying "User name will be changed". Second event will be "User name change is cancelled" whenever microservice B does not like it. Third event will be "User name change was successful".

So far it will work. But how do we implement this? I do not like to have a monolith that connects all microservices together. I like to have some "plugin" concepts. As long as we do not run microservice B there is no one ever doing a veto and we automatically should run "User name change was sucessful". But as soon as we run microservice B we should check if microservice B likes to veto the event.

And how do we devide "microservice B is not running" from "microservice B is currently offline but will be back soon"? In first situation we do not get a Veto. In second situation we must wait for B to come back again to check the pending "user name changed" events.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a dependency on Microservice B, then I would just allow the name change initially and treat denials from Microservice B like an eventual consistency exception.

So, in Microservice A you do as much as you can to ensure that the change won't cause an issue for whatever MS-B might be synchronizing to.  Then you record a "user name changed" event.

If MS-B isn't running, then you're done here, the name changed.
If MS-B *is* running, and it runs into an issue when it tries to sync the updated user name, then you go into correction mode.  Exactly what that means will depend on a number of things (how likely is the issue to occur, what's the impact, etc.).
You might have MS-B pause and send an email so a human can rectify the situation.
Or you might have MS-B issue a reversing change (another "user name changed" or a "name change reverted back to: X" - whatever makes sense for your domain).

If you issue compensating events you'll have some additional exceptions to watch for... for instance if `User A` changes their name to `User X`, and `User B` then changes their name to `User A`.  If MS-B reverses the first name change, you'll wind up with duplicate names unless you also reverse the second name change.
(Or maybe you could "lock" the old username for some amount of time before it's allowed to be re-used.)